# Handling errors raised from ActiveX EXE

Tags: error-handling, vb6, runtime-error, activex, com-interop

I am in support team of one legacy VB6 project that involves socket communication.
We got one issue in error handling.

Following are the components of this application.

- Main process
- Activex Exe process

Main process creates the activex class objects and invokes functions and consumes events (like socket connected,reading etc ) from those objects.
Main process form module have error handlers in all functions.

Main process error handler does following:

1. Log error in file
2. Show Msgbox (vbcritical style) to user

In ActiveX exe class,all functions have error handlers 
ActiveX process error handler does following

1. Log error in file
2. Raise error using `Err.raise`

We observed when a function of ActiveX class invoked from main process and some error occurs in ActiveX exe function, a runtime error message is displayed from activex exe and ActiveX process terminated even though 
error handlers are there in Main process functions.

Is there something wrong in error handlers design or error handlers in one process cannot catch the errors raised in other process?

Comment: Have you been able to run the two components in the debugger and step-trace / set breakpoints and see exactly what happens?

Comment: One guess is that a second error is being thrown within one of the error handlers.

Comment: Error handlers handle non fatal errors.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, I observed in debug (Main project and ActiveX project)..error handler in ActiveX logged error and when it reaches Err.Raise,i expected Main project module function (which called this ActiveX class function) will catch this error but it didn't happen...a runtime error message displayed instead.

Comment: ActiveX exe's are very special animals.  They should only be used if you really know the use cases for them. The way that you want error handling to work (Have the standard exe catch the error) you will need to change your ActiveX exe to an ActiveX dll.